# How to impute missing latitude and longitude in dataset using R

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, analytics, imputation

I have a dataset with 1658099 observations

[These are the variables and number of missing observations in each column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93rJn.png)

As part of preprocessing, how do I impute longitude and latitude values in it? I don't think mean of the location makes sense. And I don't want to discard them as well. Please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: could be over my head, but my 2 cents. Not sure if there is a right answer here, but I would study missMDA package and try different methods. I feel, its really question of what you feel confortable with. You have decent amount of non NA columns so imputePCA might not be worst option (even if I don't know your columns that well). This question might belong better to other venues.

Comment: You are correct. You should not discard longitude and latitude as a significant number of data are missing for both pickup and drop-off Longitude/Latitude. IMO, using most frequent value of these for same VendorID could be a good assumption.

Comment: +1 for  MKR though you should take into account the distance aswell as maybe the most frequent pickup and drop-off location are the same for some vendor id so you will get a zero length trip. Moreover you could infer the distance from the fare probably. Although as it represents like only 5% of your data, I would juste remove those rows.